# Visualizar documento PDF windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Existe alguma propriedade de visualizar um arquivo .PDF a partir do evento Click em *PictureBox* sem ter que criar um novo modal?

**Exemplo:**

Tenho essa *PictureBox*, onde criei o código abaixo, que assim que for clicado ele da opção de imprimir o arquivo, porém gostaria de deixar mais dinâmico, visualizando o .PDF e o usuário escolhe se quer ou não imprimir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código:**

```
private void picPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                NotasFiscais objNotasFiscais = new NotasFiscais();
                Pedido objPedido = new Pedido();
                if (objPedido.ConsultarNFPedido(Metodos.empresa, txtNumPedido.Text) > 0)
                {
                    objNotasFiscais.NFEmpresa = Metodos.empresa;
                    objNotasFiscais.NFNumero = objPedido.pedNFNumero;
                    objNotasFiscais.NFSerie = objPedido.pedNFSerie;
                    objNotasFiscais.NFCliente = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);
                    objNotasFiscais.NFTipo = objPedido.pedNFTipo;
                }
               if (objNotasFiscais.ConsultarNotaFiscal(Metodos.empresa, objNotasFiscais.NFNumero, objNotasFiscais.NFSerie, objNotasFiscais.NFTipo) > 0 )
                {
                   // if (objNotasFiscais.NFStatus == "I")
                   // {
                        Operacoes operacoes = new Operacoes();
                        string danfe = operacoes.ConsultarDanfePdf(objNotasFiscais.NFEmpresa, objNotasFiscais.NFNumero, objNotasFiscais.NFSerie, objNotasFiscais.NFCliente.ToString(), objNotasFiscais.NFTipo, true);
                        string Filepath = danfe;
                        new PrintPDF(danfe);
                    //}
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("PDF da Danfe não encontrado.", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tive um problema similar recentemente e andei pesquisando algo para visualizar PDF em uma aplicação WindowsForms e acabei encontrando esse projeto  [Moon PDF](https://github.com/reliak/moonpdf).

Trata-se de um controle WPF então será necessário utilizar um controle WPF na sua aplicação Windows Forms.

Fiz um projeto de exemplo no Github e você dar uma olhada nesse [link](https://github.com/odairjgn/PDF-Test).

Essa biblioteca utilizada está disponível na galeria nuget nesse [pacote](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoonPdfLib-x86/).